# IDA ATL C++ class reconstruction

Tags: ida, c++, class-reconstruction

I'm currently using IDA Pro to analyze a dll, but IDA Pro doesn't analyze ATL standard classes properly, including CString, so I'm trying to reconstruct the classes manually, but I'm having some problems.

***- I need to create a header file in C format to register many classes at once, which is too much work because classes are usually hierarchical.***

***- While member variable names and some virtual functions can be renamed automatically, simple methods need to be named manually.***

Is there a more efficient way to solve these problems?